# How to generate report for Code Coverage in Hybris

Tags: jacoco, sap-commerce-cloud

How can the unit test results of a hybris project be captured to jacoco.exec.
i am using h1808 version. Please share step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, you should be able to set it up with the help of https://wiki.hybris.com/display/forum/running+Sonar+and+JaCoCo+on+hybris

[image]

Comment: Thank u for u r answer.That works fine. But there is an issue when i m using ant unittests -Dtestclasses.extensions="myextension" the code coverage report not showing the status of myextesion. I have opened jacoco.exec in eclipse and select all required extesion but it shows n/a for "myextension".

Comment: I have tried this using eclemma eclipse plugin for each test classes separately. And it shows                             java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bnt.paymentcommunication.jalo.PaymentcommunicationTest
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)